# ArraySlice in Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, facebook-graph-api, prefix

after using the prefix method on an Array I get what is called an arraySlice. How can I transform this into an Array?

I am trying to fetch Ints from FacebookGraphApi then asking for the first 3 (prefix(3)) and trying to add them into a new array.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just initialize a new `Array` with the slice:

```
let arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let slice = arr1[2...5]
let arr2 = Array(slice)
```